# CSS conflicts with <br> tag

Tags: html, css

I have the following html and CSS code

```
<body>
        <div class='topBar'>
            <form action='q.php' method='GET' class='sPage'>
                <input type='text' class='search lt' placeholder='Search' name='s' autofocus='autofocus' style='border-bottom:0px;'>
                <input type='submit' class='srchBtn lt' value='Go' style='background:#FFF; color:#E40046;'>
            </form>
        </div>
</body>
```

When I try to give the following css code for the above HTML code,

```
.sPage{
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 25px; 
}
```

The problem is that the margin-top property also brings down the toBar div. I only want it to bring the sPage down. How can I fix it

Comment: For me its working https://jsfiddle.net/w2q01e8n/ Probably other CSS is conflicting. Also in your html there is no br tag

Comment: your code work well,change `margin-top:50px` and see result.

Comment: @ehsan I have updated my problem. Please go through the question again

Comment: @Frankusky Question updated with the problem

Comment: Use `padding-top` instead - https://jsfiddle.net/v61ja45m/

Comment: What do you mean conflicts with `br` tag, there is no mention of `br` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If no other CSS is conflicting, it's probably that the margin-top is too low, maybe you don't notice any change because 5px from the top is almost nothing. Try increasing the value to 30px or 50px and you'll notice the margin.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on position attribute of parent and child element.

If the parent position is `absolute` or `fixed`:

1. the child with any position will margin top from the top border of the parent

If the parent position is `relative` of `static`:

2. the child with position `relative` or `static` will make the parent margin top
3. the child with position `absolute` or `fixed` will margin top from the top border of the parent

**Description image** from left to right is the case 1, 2, 3. The green square is the parent, the red square is the child, and the gray square is the grandparent with any position.

Red: `margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 50px`

[image]